# What does the ts function do in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have downloaded the historical prices between `Jan-1-2010` and `Dec-31-2014` for ***Twitter, Inc. (TWTR) -NYSE*** from [YAHOO! FINANCE](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TWTR&a=00&b=1&c=2010&d=00&e=1&f=2015&g=d) in a *twitter.csv* file.

I then loaded it into *RStudio* using:

```
x = read.csv("Z:/path/to/file/twitter.csv", header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Here is how table x looks like:

```
View(x)
```

[image]

Then I used *ts function* to get the time series of Adj.Close:

```
x.ts = ts(x$Adj.Close, frequency = 12, start=c(2010,1), end=c(2014,12)

x.ts
```

[image]

How the previous results have been obtained? They are really different from table x data. Do they need any adjustements?

Comment: please show complete code so we know which packages you are using

Comment: It's just an example. I used ts function (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html) to obtain a time series on Adj.Close. But I don't understand what I get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is the scale in which the data are read. With `frequency = 12, start=c(2010,1), end=c(2014,12)` you are telling the function that you have one number per month. If you have one number per day, as it's your case, you should try with:

```
    x.ts = ts(x$Adj.Close, frequency = 365, start=c(2010,1), end=c(2014,365)
```

Comment: Very good. And in my case, with frequency=12, what is, for example, 35.87 for (jan,2010)? The average?

Comment: In your case, 35.87 is the value for row 1 (2014-12-31), then your wrongly labeled "Feb 2010" is actually the value for row 2 (2014-12-30) and so forth. I forgot to mention that you should also reverse the order of your data if you want to build your time series correctly. Function `rev` may come handy, either applied on the table or within the parameter passed to `ts`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, frequency should be set to 365 if you deal with daily data, 12 if monthly etc.
   Secondly
2. Secondly, I think you need to arrange the data ascending chronologically before using the ts() function.

The function blindly follows exactly what you are telling it, e.g. the data from the chart starts with the first value 35.87 in 2014-12-31 but the start date in the code is 2010, January, meaning it will attribute that value to being associated with Jan-2010.

```
x <- x %>%
  dplyr::arrange(date)
ts.x <- ts(x$Adj.Close, frequency = 365, start=min(x$date), end=max(x$date))
```